# Number of divisors in a range [a,b], a and b can be large numbers

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

Suppose for finding number of divisors of all numbers between 1 and N, we use:

```
for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) 
    for (j = i; j < N; j += i) 
        factors[j]++;
```

What should we do if the range is something like `[a,b]` such that `1 < a,b < 10^9 and b-a < 10,000?`
If we adapt the code above as:

```
for (i = 1; i < b; ++i)
    for (j = i; j < b; j += i)
        factors[j]++;
```

it would take too much time to run if `b = 10^9`. So what kind of optimization can be made, given that b-a is small relative to a and b, and a and b are large (10^9 or more)?

PS. Maybe I couldn't explain the problem well. What I actually need to find is how many numbers in the range have number of divisors equal to some `x <= 100.`

*Thanks.*

Comment: You are not using a anywhere ?

Comment: The question is interesting but it probably needs to be improved/fixed.

Comment: The second algorithm also requires 10^9 space, so it's not good. The loops could be run between a and b, or 1 and b-a, but I don't know how it can be done.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It sounds like a task on SPOJ, or homework.

Comment: My algorithm is wrong on multiple levels, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is to calculate the factorization of each number of interest, then use that to calculate the number of divisors: if the factorization is a^w * b^x * c^y * d^z then the number of divisors is (w+1) * (x+1) * (y+1) * (z+1).

You can find the factorization in a couple of ways. One way is by trial division; since the limit of 10^9 is small, trial division will work without too much pain. Another way is by sieving, using a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes to find the factors, then calculating their multiplicities by division.

You can find algorithms and code for trial division, the segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes, and calculating the divisors of a number on [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com). Click on Exercises on the menu bar, then Themes, then select Prime Numbers.

EDIT: Here's how I would do it.

The first step is to sieve for the factors of all the numbers in the range. Calculate the primes less than the square root of *b* using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Create an array of length *b* - *a* + 1 with each element initialized to an empty list. For each prime less than the square root of *b* calculate the first number *k* greater than or equal to *a* that is a multiple of the prime, then for each array element starting at *k* - *a* and at intervals of *p* -- *k* - *a* + *p*, *k* - *a* + 2 *p*, *k* - *a* + 3 *p*, and so on -- add *p* to the list at the array location. That gives you a list of the factors of all the numbers in the range, but not their multiplicities.

The second step is to calculate the number of divisors of all the numbers in the range. Each element *i* of the array contains a list. If the list is empty, the number is prime, and the number *a* + *i* has two divisors. Otherwise, use trial division by the known factors in the list to determine their multiplicities, and use those multiplicities to calculate the number of divisors.

Then you just count those in the range with a number of divisors equal to *x*.

Comment: Yes, I tried prime factorization and sieve, but I need to find number of divisors for all numbers between a and b. For example, a=10^9-10^4 and b = 10^9. And there can be something like 30 separate sets of input maybe. I need a faster method.

Comment: Factorization actually works quite fast, but I need something faster.

Comment: The first step doesn't give you the list of all factors. e.g. numbers in the form small prime * big prime. Your algorithm can be modified a bit to make it work, though.

Comment: Of course not. Any remaining prime greater than the largest sieving prime will not be on the list of factors. You'll resolve that in the second step.

Comment: @user448810: There is no need to keep a list. Just keep an array of all numbers in range a..b, loop through the multiples of primes and find multiplicity + factorize the numbers.

Comment: This is the fragment of code of what I was talking about: https://gist.github.com/4347988. I tested the code properly this time...

Comment: That looks okay. You combined the two steps into one, which saves some space. I kept the explanation of the two steps separate because it's easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

For any number n such as : 1 < a <= n <= b < 10^9 , a pretty simple algorithm will give you the prime decomposition of n (you don't need to go further than sqrt(n)). Then one you have it, a formula will give you the number of different divisors.

As the number of n you have to handle the pretty small, this should work.

Comment: I tried prime decomposition for each number, but I need to find number of divisors for all numbers between a and b. For example, a=10^9-10^4 and b = 10^9. And there can be something like 30 separate inputs maybe. I need a faster method.

Comment: Factorization actually works quite fast, but I need something faster.